# Why aren't bools compared by just one last bit?

Tags: c++, boolean, bit

Recently when using gtest at work I've received some interesting error code that made me wondering:

```
error: Expected: b1
      Which is: true
To be equal to: b2
      Which is: true
```

This is the result of the test `EXPECT_EQ(bool b1, bool b2)` (pseudo code). I've done some digging and this is the example code with comments:

```
{
    bool b1, b2; //uninitialized bool variables
    //lets say we are a good programmer
    b1 = b2 = true;
    if(b1)
      if(b2)
           if(b1 == b2)
               std::cout << "You are a good programmer!" << std::endl;
}
{
    bool b1, b2; //uninitialized bool variables
    //but we are not always good programmers - b1 and b2 remains uninitialized
    auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&b1);
    *p1 = 3;
    auto p2 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&b2);
    *p2 = 7;
    //code above is a simulation that b1 and b2 contains some trash that was left in the memory
    if(b1){
        std::cout << "b1 is true. \n";
        if(b2){
            std::cout << "b2 is true. \n";
            if(b1 == b2)
                std::cout << "b1 == b2" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "b1 != b2" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
You are a good programmer!
b1 is true.
b2 is true. 
b1 != b2
```

At first, this makes sense, you play with UB, you get what you deserve. And I know simple solution for this is "Be a good programmer and always initialize variables" but for me, shown behavior makes debugging harder, since you'd expect the third if to always be true if previous two were, no matter if the state of boolean variables were initialized or not. Running example code with ints instead of bools would made perfect sense for me - if C++ treats 0 as `false` and anything else as `true`, checking ints in `if(some_int)` would check for non-zero number, then comparing them would compare actual numbers.

But with bools, I would expect comparison 'function' to check between only two states - true and false, by comparing last bit of a byte, not all eight comparing between 255 possible states.

So my question is:

Why C++ when comparing bools, compares whole byte, instead of just one last bit containing true/false information.

[Minimum reproducible example](https://godbolt.org/z/cWdPrK)

Comment: Using uninitialized values results in _undefined behavior_ in C++. If used correctly all boolean variables may have only two values that represent `true` and `false`. Integers would be converted via the standard boolean conversion to one of the two admissible values (cf. 4.12 [conv.bool]). So no need to check all 255 possible values. See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2192253/1328439

Comment: It's generally cheaper to just compare two values than to mask out bits and compare them. In **valid** C++ code the result is the same: the two `bool` values compare equal. Once you've wandered off into the land of undefined behavior, there's no meaningful result from that code, so there's no point in the compiler generating sub-optimal code to take account for it.

Comment: Also it would make the logic of booleans way worse than now: Image you don't assign 3 and 7, but 3 and 4. Now both are true, but - according to the logic you proposed - they are not equal, because the last bit is not equal.

Comment: *but for me, shown behavior makes debugging harder* --  Update your testing suite to include a static analyzer to detect uninitialized variables, or if your compiler is smart enough to warn you, don't throw those warnings away.

Comment: Crashes on my machine, with `runtime error: load of value 3, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'`.  Pesky undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eljay -- Probably the debug version of your compiler runtime is flagging the error, and `assert()`-ing?  Regardless, the compiler is free to do anything (UB), even help out the programmer by issuing an assert().

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie • isn't the debug version, it's the clang variant I'm using... an instrumented version of clang that emits highly inefficient & pessimized code, albeit with all sorts of experimental sanitizing checks in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word: efficiency.  It takes fewer machine code instructions to compare two bytes than two bits since in the latter case an additional mask instruction is needed.

See example on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/uJ2xXy